# Use Mockito to test that super was not called

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

Can I use Mockito to test whether calling a method on my object calls through to the super implementation? I can't find a way to do this. Basically I want something like this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunnerWithInjection.class)
public class TestFragmentTest {
    @Spy private TestFragment testFragment;

    @Test
    public void onConfigurationChanged_shouldNotCallSuper() {
        doThrow(new RuntimeException("Should not call super!")).when(superOf(testFragment))
            .onConfigurationChanged(null);

        testFragment.onConfigurationChanged(null);
    }

    private static class TestFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }
    }
}
```

There of course is no `superOf` utility in Mockito, but this expresses the behavior I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you have to assert this? Sounds like your test will be tightly coupled to the implementation, rather than testing the contract?

Comment: @NilsH is correct. This is why you should also favor composition over inheritance.

Comment: I agree, favor composition over inheritance. Unfortunately I have no control over how the boys at Google decide to write their frameworks. Given this is trying to test Android code, and the super class does all sorts of things I'm trying to avoid here that I can't make assertions on, hence I simply want to make sure that super is not called.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this could be to put a special variable in you superclass that gets initialized only in the constructor that you call in you subclass.

This way you could add a function that checks if the variable has been changed in the superclass.

Comment: The superclass is not mine to edit. It's Android framework code.